# HBase OutOfMemory Error

Tags: java, eclipse, hbase

iam trying to connect to remote hbase server through java client (eclipse) using hbasetemplate. I am getting the below OutOfMemory error. I tried increasing the client(eclipse) JVM heap but still didnt work. Any clue on what this exception related to exactly ?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:390)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:358)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:328)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Operation.<clinit>(Operation.java:40)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:165)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.prefetchRegionCache(HConnectionManager.java:1158)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1222)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1110)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1067)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:326)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:165)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseUtils.getHTable(HbaseUtils.java:76)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate.getTable(HbaseTemplate.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate.execute(HbaseTemplate.java:54)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate.get(HbaseTemplate.java:170)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate.get(HbaseTemplate.java:160)
at edu.mayo.registry.fhir.rest.hbase.repository.HbaseRepository.partialScan(HbaseRepository.java:50)
at edu.mayo.registry.fhir.rest.controller.ESController.putIndexValue(ESController.java:61)
at edu.mayo.registry.fhir.rest.controller.ESController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$729642a0.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are doing which might be causing you to exceed your Perm Gen space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When getting `PermGen space` OOM you should increase size of PermGen using `-XX:MaxPermSize` JVM command line option, e.g. `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`

If you are using eclipse you should put it into 'VM Arguments' box in the 'Run Configurations' dialog